# Keep state of Activity UI after leaving and reentering it in Android-App

Tags: android, android-activity

In my Android App I have a main activity and some other activities. The others get started with a button from the main one.

When I enter an activity and for example toggle some toggleViews, return back to main view and then again enter the sub activity, **all the changes are lost**.

Changing the `manifest.xml` to

```
    <activity android:name="MySubActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>
```

does not help.

Also the Methods `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` do not work because the sub activity gets killed as soon as I leave it. So the data is saved but it can never be loaded because the Bundle of `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` seems to be always `null`.

How can I keep the status of all the inputs (*better*) or prevent the activity from getting killed (*worse*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save data somewhere persistent, like database, preferences, serialized objects. You are starting a new activity not restarting the old one.

Comment: That worked for me. I Safed the status in the [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). But it feels very strange because in fact i do not need the data to be kept when I reboot the phone or reload the app.